# Почему виртуальная функция базового класса не вызывается при приведении указателя производного класса к указателю на базовый класс?

Tags: c++

Есть простая тестовая программа:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class a1 {
public:
    void printid() { cout << endl << "this is a1 id"; }
};

class a2 : public a1 {
public:
    void printid() { cout << endl << "this is a2 id"; };
};

int main() {
    a1 aa1;
    a2 aa2;

    a1* aa1_ptr = &aa1;
    a2* aa2_ptr = &aa2;

    a1* aa1_ptr_derived = (a1*)aa2_ptr;

    aa1.printid();
    aa2.printid();

    aa1_ptr->printid();
    aa2_ptr->printid();

    aa1_ptr_derived->printid();

    return 0;
}
```

Результат работы этой программы такой:

```
this is a1 id   
this is a2 id   
this is a1 id   
this is a2 id   
this is a1 id
```

Если сделать функции printid() виртуальными, то результат существенно меняется.
А именно, если программа такая:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class a1 {
public:
    virtual void printid() { cout << endl << "this is a1 id"; }
};

class a2 : public a1 {
public:
    virtual void printid() { cout << endl << "this is a2 id"; };
};

int main() {
    a1 aa1;
    a2 aa2;

    a1* aa1_ptr = &aa1;
    a2* aa2_ptr = &aa2;

    a1* aa1_ptr_derived = (a1*)aa2_ptr;

    aa1.printid();
    aa2.printid();

    aa1_ptr->printid();
    aa2_ptr->printid();

    aa1_ptr_derived->printid();

    return 0;
}
```

Результат работы этой программы такой:

```
this is a1 id   
this is a2 id   
this is a1 id   
this is a2 id   
this is a2 id
```

То есть, когда я пытаюсь вызвать виртуальную функцию от указателя на базовый класс, полученного приведением производного указателя к базовому, то вызывается виртуальная функция производного класса.

Вопросы:

1. Разве это правильно? Ведь когда я вызываю printid() от указателя на базовый класс, я получаю "this is a1 id". А когда я вызываю printid() от такого же указателя на базовый класс, но полученного приведением от производного класса, то почему-то вызывается "this is a2 id"?

UPD1:

Sorry, коллеги, это я затупил капитально. Удалять вопрос не буду, пусть висит на страх студентам. Просто обычно при проектировании я смотрел на иерархию снизу вверх и хотел получить полиморфное поведение для указателя на базовый класс. И получал-таки. А тут почему-то я посмотрел на иерархию сверху вниз и почему-то решил, что при спуске по иерархии должен получать все свойства базовых классов.

Comment: Ым... Но в этом вся суть виртуальных функций!

Comment: Да, это правильно. Именно так и работает полиморфизм

Comment: @AnT А, ну да. Чего-то я затупил капитально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поведение, которое вы наблюдаете во втором случае - это вся суть виртуальных функций. Это то, для чего они и предназначены. Поэтому не ясно, почему вас удивляет наблюдаемое поведение.

По определению виртуальной функции, выбор конкретной функции в вызове делается в соответствии с *динамическим* типом объекта, использованного в вызове. Т.к. в вызове

```
aa1_ptr_derived->printid();
```

указатель `aa1_ptr_derived` фактически указывает на объект типа `a2`, то вызывается функция именно из класса `a2`. В этом и заключается вся идея полиморфизма.

Формально в языке С++ "подавить" полиморфизм можно только одним способом: указать в вызове квалифицированное имя метода

```
aa1_ptr_derived->a1::printid();
```

(плюс особенности виртуальных вызовов в конструкторах и деструкторах).

Answer (score 0):

> Разве это правильно?

да, так задумано.

Реализовано это через таблицу виртуальных функций. Когда вызывается виртуальная функция, то она обычно вызывается по номеру в таблице. Адрес таблицы хранится внутри объекта. Но таблица привязана к классу, а не объекту.

Что делает компилятор? если он знает, что это обычная функция, он сразу подставляет её адрес. Если он видит, что это виртуальная функция, то он по адресу объекта вычисляет адрес таблицы (очень часто это просто +4 или что то в этом роде) Потом в полученном адресе таблицы находит по номеру нужную виртуальную функцию и там будет ее адрес.

Приведение указателя к предку не меняет сути вычисления адреса таблицы. Собственно и имеем.

P.S. в многих случаях, компилятор может определить вызываемую функцию и так. И таблицами виртуальных функций не пользуется.